# using localhost and server localhost simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I was using typical php mysql script but it was causing heavy load on server so thought of using my personal pc and installed wamp so now i want to select the data from my pc localhost mysql and insert the data to website server localhost . so how can i do that.

i have only one simple script which selects data from mysql and insert data into mysql if it satisfies the criteria but how can i do it for two connection in a script .

select will use mypc wamp localhost and insert will use server localhost .table name can be same . here is my code

```
     <?php
           include('connect.php'); 
           $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablea` where status = '1' order by id asc LIMIT 5");
           // tableA is in my personal PC localhost   
           while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
             //  Do Something    
            mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tableb (title,content,url) VALUES ('$title1','$content','$url')");
             // tableB is in my website localhost

         } 
           mysql_query("update tablea set status='2' where type='$type' ");
           //my personal pc localhost
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Can't you just dump your server's database using any export tool like phpmyadmin or mysqldump.

Comment: You would need to make separate connections to the local mysql server and the remote.

Comment: @vangelion how to make connection to remote server from mypc php code can you please guide

Comment: @deadlock yes  i thought what you said earlier but again it will become manual process

Comment: @OP I haven't done PHP for a long time so I really can't. You could try reading through 'connect.php'. But 'deadlock's suggestion is probably the right thing to do anyway.

Comment: If you really wanted both databases to be in sync, you would need to set up replication between the two.  Don't bother, this is going to be incredibly slow with your current setup.  Also, you're probably wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid that problem.

Comment: What i have is a local mysql server via wamp and a hosted mysql server. I have setup a few SSH scripts to import / export different parts of my live database to a folder on the host. I then have a few windows batch scripts that import / export from wamp to the host. I do all of my work on the local server, then just run the scripts to update my website... That takes a huge amount of downtime / issues away from my hosted site and its users and it's much faster working locally. Regarding your question however, you would need 2 separate mysql connections in php, so `$linkLocal` and `$linkHosted`.

Comment: There be all sort of DEAMONS in this idea that nobody here can attempt to mitigate as we cannot see what the database is being used for and how it is being used. Also it is likely that the bulk of the runtime is taken up by the INSERT and UPDATE and not the SELECT. You may not actuall be saving very much time. Would it be better to rethink a solution, along the lines of a CRON that runs every 15 minutes and takes small bites at doing the amendments. This way there would be less to do in one chunk and things would be updated every 15 minutes rather than once a day.